# what is the "non-linear" algebra called?

Tags: linear-algebra

Linear algebra studies mapping between vector spaces. But, when these mappings are non-linear, what is the branch of mathematics that studies them? The term *linear* algebra somehow implies that it is a special case of a more general algebra, but I've never come across a such thing.

To give a particular example, the problem I'm mostly interested in is:

Given a matrix $A$ with size $3 \times 2$ and some input coordinates $[x, y]^T$, linear algebra tells us that

- the coordinates are mapped to a $3$-dimensional space
- the mapping looks something like $[2x, 3y+x, y+1]$
- the set of all possible $(x, y)$ pairs produces a $2$-dimensional plane in the $3$-dimensional space

But, what if my mapping was not linear? Let's say I map $(x, y)$ to $[x^2 + y, \sin(x/y), \exp(y)]$. What does that produce in the new $3$-dimensional space and what does it look like? (it seems to produce a $2$-dimensional manifold of unpredictable shape). What branch of mathematics do I need to study to better understand the geometry of non-linear mappings/spaces/operators?

In case it's relevant: I mostly motivated by machine learning, where this kind of mapping comes up in various cases, from linear regression in "feature spaces" to support vector machines.

Comment: Algebraic geometry?

Comment: @Randall: probably. I have no idea.There are many branches called "algebra" and I have no clear picture as to how they are related. Would you say this is the appropriate branch for my particular problem?

Comment: I think the answer to your question depends on what you need to do with the answer, so can you explain more.  There are many branches of maths that might  be useful. For instance sometimes you can linearise locally using calculus, analyse the multivariable function for peaks and troughs, and so on. Have a look at some more advanced calculus books and they may help.  If you need to go in further, ask the question again, with a bit more precision. Also check up on the topics mentioned in the answer to the linked question mentioned above.

Comment: @TimPorter: thanks for the comment. I don't want to optimize/approximate something, just get a picture of how the geometry changes when you use non-linear mappings instead of linear.

Comment: @blue_note: in that case perhaps the best thing is to get hold of a good graphing program and then try out some slightly non-linear examples, for instance look at mappings with a quadratic part in their description. Avoid sin and exp and stick to polynomials. (There is a lot of stuff out there, of course, but look at sources that treat, for instance, conic sections, etc. You can get quite some way with  using linear algebra then, as I said, it depends what you want from the study. Look at the zeros of some of the mappings, i.e. thepoints which map to zero.)